# discontinuous BitBlt capture

Tags: windows, api, capture, interrupt, bitblt

I am using BitBlt heavily in my project. I create a number of threads and in each thread I capture the screen by BitBlt. It works great and as expected for now except the following problem.

The problem happens when the user clicks on a running program or for example already opened explorer on the taskbar. You know when you click on the running program on the taskbar, it either minimizes or appears on the screen. The issue that I am talking about happens just in this transition. At that moment, something like an interrupt, all threads stop capturing the screen for a fraction of a second and then they continue capturing. The same thing happen when you move down or up the thing on the volume control window. Could you please shed some light why this is happening and how I can prevent this happening?

Thanks.

Jay

Comment: This is almost certainly caused by Aero.  You are not reading video memory with BitBlt anymore, Aero composites the bitmap.  Which odds that it stops doing this temporarily when it displays the window animation.  No simple workaround for this of course.

Comment: Nope. Aero is off. This happens without aero. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a scheduling issue.  When you activate an app, it gets a small, momentary boost in its priority (so that it can seem responsive in the UI).  This boost might last about as long as the animation and momentarily pre-empt your screen capture threads.

It's also possible that the desktop manager is serializing stuff, and your bitblts are simply stalled until the animation is over. Even if you've turned Aero off, I believe the [desktop window manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969540(v=vs.85).aspx) may still be in compositing mode, which has the effect Hans Passant was describing in the comments.

If you're trying to make a video from the screen, I think it's going to be impossible to rely on GDI.  I strongly suggest reading about the Desktop Window Manager. For example, this [caveat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969536(v=vs.85).aspx) directly applies to what you're trying to do:

> Avoid reading from or writing to a display DC. Although supported by DWM, we do not recommend it because of decreased performance.

When you use GDI to try to read the screen, DWM has to stop what it's doing, possibly render a fresh copy of the desktop to video memory, and to copy data from video memory back to system memory.  It's possible that the DWM treats these as lower-priority requests than an animation in progress, so by the time it responds to the BitBlt, the animation is over.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112831/how-to-make-screen-capture-video-using-direct-show-net-library) suggests that DirectShow with a screen capture filter might be the way to go.